# Group By on Join in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I am working with:

(i) a table called `Income` which looks like this -

[image]

(ii) a table called `Attribute` which looks like this -

[image]

(iii) and a table called `AccountCustomOrder` which looks like this -

[image]

The output that I'm trying to achieve(similar to a PIVOT TABLE in sql) would look like something like this(grouped by AccountCode):
[image]

Now, in order to achieve it with LINQ, I have tried this:

```
public List<AccountLevelData> GetGroupedAccountLevelData(long jobId){

var data = (from in in _dbContext.Set<Income>()
                          join at in _dbContext.Set<Attribute>()
                          on in.AttributeSetId equals ar.AttributeSetId
                          join co in _dbContext.Set<AccountCustomOrder>()
                          on in.AccountCode equals co.AccountCode
                          where in.JobId == jobId
                          select new AccountLevelData
                          {
                              AccountCode = in.AccountCode,
                              AccountDescription = co.AccountDescription,
                              AccountOrder = co.AccountOrder,
                              AccountAttributes = new AccountAttributes
                              {
                                  AttributeAValue= (at.AttributeValue == "Attribute A Value") ? in.FunctionalAmt : 0,
                                  AttributeBValue= (at.AttributeValue == "Attribute B Value") ? in.FunctionalAmt : 0
                              }
                          }).ToList()

return data;
    }
```

But I'm not sure how to group the joined data in order to achieve the desired data(grouped by AccountCode).
Can anyone suggest?

Comment: It seems that group by is not what you want, I guess each account code is unique, You want the attribute value for each attribute name and that is the tricky part. Curious to see an answer to this question.

Comment: @jonathana each Account Code is unique alright but there can be multiple line items corresponding to a particular Account Code(with different Attribute Values). So I was wondering if a 2 level of grouping can be done - first by Account Code and then by Attribute Value; not sure if that is the correct approach though

Comment: I do not know how much data you are processing, but it may be worth considering the possibility of reducing it as much as possible with a LINQ query and the rest to perform in C# logic, and if efficiency is required and can be sorted numerically then use binary searches

Comment: You should use the linq group keyword. You can see it in action [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325306/14800433)